# Hwclock shows wrong output with custom RTC driver

Tags: driver, embedded-linux, real-time-clock, hwclock

I'm trying to use a DS3231 with a Beaglebone Black. I'm custom system I built with buildroot (BusyBox v1.31.1), I also wrote the driver I'm using, this is an university assignment, so I can't use prebuilt systems or any existing drivers.

I'm building with Linaro's linux cross compiler (v7.5.0 2019.12) and using kernel version 5.10.65-ti-r30.

The system detects the RTC and my driver probes successfully, it generates an RTC file in `/dev/rtc2` and I can set the time in the RTC with `hwclock --systohc -f /dev/rtc2`, but whenever I read it with `hwclock -f /dev/rtc2` it says it's 1 second before the Unix epoch (1969/12/31 23:59:59). I've also written an userspace program that uses `ioctl()` to read and set the RTC and it sets and reads the time with no problems, so I know my driver is working.

I've also modified the time in the internal RTC in `/dev/rtc0`, and `hwclock` outputs its time with no problems.

Here's the output of my rtc when using my program and `hwclock`:

```
# ./a.out r /dev/rtc2
Time read: 2023/07/24 19:03:22
# hwclock -f /dev/rtc2
Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 1969  0.000000 seconds
```

The date shown on `hwclock` should be the same as my program. If I put `pr_info()` statements inside the driver to print the time they print the correct time.

Here's the read function from my driver:

```c
static int ds3231_read_time(struct device* dev, struct rtc_time* tm){
    struct i2c_client* client = to_i2c_client(dev);
    s32 ret;
    u8 reg;
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_SEC);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during seconds read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_sec = 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_SEC);
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_MIN);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during minutes read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_min = 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_MIN);
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_HRS);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during hours read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_hour = 20 * ((reg >> 5) & 1) + 10 * ((reg >> 4) & 1) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_HR);
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_MDAY);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during day read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_mday = 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_DAY);
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_MON);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during month read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_mon = 10 * ((reg >> 4) & 1) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_MON);
    ret = i2c_smbus_read_byte_data(client, DS3231_REG_YEAR);
    if(ret < 0){
        pr_err("Error %d during year read\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    reg = (u8)(ret);
    tm->tm_year = 2000 + 100 * (tm->tm_mon >> 7) + 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_YEAR);
    tm->tm_wday = calculate_wday(tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday);
    tm->tm_yday = calculate_yday(tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday);
    tm->tm_isdst = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think this function is causing the problems, but I'm including it just in case.

Comment: What does `tm->tm_mon >> 7` do in determining `tm->tm_year`?  If it does anything then what is the value of `tm->tm_mon`? Not 0 to 11 clearly.

Comment: @Clifford The RTC saves a century bit in the MSB of the month, the year register saves a value between 0 and 99, the century bit allows it to work for dates 100 years more (up to 2199). The value of tm->tm_mon is 1-12.

Comment: Maybe so but the previous masking with DS3231_MSK_MON will have removed that from `tm->tm_mon`.  It is the register that has that field, not `tm->tm_mon`.   You need to retain the `DS3231_REG_MON` value or extract the century from it _before_ getting `DS3231_REG_YEAR` - clearly `tm->tm_mon` does not contain the value of `DS3231_REG_MON`

Comment: ... interesting that you try to justify this in your comment but in your own answer, you concede that it was indeed incorrect.  The years since 1900 thing I was going to mention, but it was academic given the nonsense with `tm_mon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering around I was able to fix this; it turns out there was actually a bug in my driver, the field `tm_year` in `struct rtc_time` stores the years since 1900, not the current year.

The line:

```c
tm->tm_year = 2000 + 100 * (tm->tm_mon >> 7) + 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_YEAR);
```

Has a problem, it adds 2000 to the year field, so it turns the field into 2023, however, it should actually contain 123 (2023 - 1900 = 123).

I also modified the month part, so that the value read from the RTC is saved before modifying, as the unmodified value needs to be used in the year calculation. It ended up looking like this:

```c
reg = (u8)(ret);
last_message = reg;
tm->tm_mon = 10 * ((reg & DS3231_MSK_10MON) >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_MON);
```

Then, instead of using `tm->tm_mon` in the year calculation, I'm now using `last_message`:

```c
tm->tm_year = 100 * (last_message >> 7) + 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_YEAR);
```

Besides that, I made sure that my userspace program subtracts and adds 1 to the month when reading and writing, respectively, so that the RTC saves a number between 0 and 12, this is because Linux reads months in this range.

Comment: It would make far more sense to have `u8 century = reg >> 7 ;` rather then `last_message`. (stylistically speaking).  Then `tm->tm_year = 100 * century + 10 * (reg >> 4) + (reg & DS3231_MSK_YEAR);`